# Django-lfs file installation

Tags: django, python-2.6

I am getting a problem in installing `Django-lfs`, following the installation steps from [this document](http://docs.getlfs.com/en/latest/introduction/installation.html).

When i run the command `cd lfs-installer` on GiT bash or command line I am getting `"No such file or Directory"`.
I am trying to check that python26 is installed or not through command line and it is not taking it as a command.
None of the command is working from the doc.

After that when i run the command `python bootstrap.py` it gives an error:

> while Initializing:   error: Couldn't open c:\django-lfs-0.7.7.tar.gz\builout.cfg

Please anyone help me with this problem. I really need to install this file.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to expand the archive; but you don't need to follow all those steps.

First, download and install [`pillow`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow). Make sure you select the version that matches your version of Python.

Next, run `easy_install django-lfs` from a command prompt. This will download and install `django-lfs`.

Comment: hi,i did archived that file through winzar so i didnt need to follow the 1st step in doc, while installing pillow its giving an error message python2.7 version not found in registery when i clicked on next option..python is installed in my system

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: through command line"python setup.py install"..i installed python2.7 for win7 64bit..python is fine it is working..i need to open a project made on django for that i need django-lfs file

Comment: You need to install Python using the [windows binary installer](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/).

Comment: i have installed buildout by using easy_install through command line easy_install zc.buildout but still not working